# Graph API + C# SDK: Create event without end date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, date

I'm having an issue when I create events from my app, basically if I don't set the "end_time" parameter for the created event, Facebook creates an event that ends 3 hours after the start time.

I'm using this code:

```
var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
arguments.Add("name", "My Activity");
arguments.Add("start_time", "2012/08/15 10:00");
var client = new FacebookWebClient(fbAccessToken);
client.Post("/me/events/", arguments);
```

And the event shows up correctly, the only problem is that the time says:

```
10:00am until 1:00pm
```

I have tried setting the end_time parameter to an empty string and null, but in both cases it fails saying that the end time cannot be before the start time.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: when do you want the event to end?

Comment: I just want to have an open end date. When you manually create an event you don't have to specify an end date/time, it shouldn't be mandatory for events created with the api either.